# Losing Session Variables in New Page ColdFusion 2018 internet explorer

Tags: session, internet-explorer, cookies, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 2018 on a Windows 2016 server. ColdFusion is fully updated.

I work in a University setting and end users have little to no control over their ie settings. All computers are (supposedly) kept to the same settings. If they aren't end users can't change them. Compatibility mode is set to on and pushed to all computers.

I am unable to reproduce this issue on my computer in Chrome, ie or any other browser. Some users, with no real rhyme or reason that we can identify, lose their session variables when they open a new window from a link.

Here's how it works:
User logs in, session variables are set. userID and sectionAccess are two of them.
User search for an employee
User gets an employee list
User clicks on a name
New window opens with complete employee details

For SOME users, the session variables are just disappearing. We can't figure out why, and there doesn't seem to be a connection between the users or their computer settings. Laptop or desktop.

The problem is also not consistent. This just came in an email from one of the affected users "I also tried again in IE and first it worked, and then logged out and tried again and it didn’t work the next few times."

It works as expected at all times on my computer and my home computer (a mac.) My computer is Windows 10, with ie 11.1565.16299.0

This is my application tag:

```
<cfapplication name="theSite"
               clientmanagement="yes"
               sessionmanagement="yes"
               setclientcookies="yes"
               sessiontimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,1,60,0)#"
               applicationtimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,1,60,0)#">
```

Has anyone experienced this? How do I fix it? Again, I have no control over browser settings.

Thank you

Comment: Application variables should last far longer than session variables. Days vs. minutes. Are the users losing their session while they are working in the system or is it gone after they've stepped away for more than an hour? Are you using `CFID` + `CFTOKEN` or `jsessionid` for session cookies? Have you verified that the new window has the session cookie set? Also, make sure the URLs are all using the same domain. `domain.edu` is a different application scope as `www.domain.edu` even if they both end up at the same site.

Comment: Do you know what IE versions are involved? When the user returns to the original window (you said a new one opens), is their session still active? Does it happen consistently for the users affected? Any commonality in anti-virus or browser privacy settings?

Comment: The users are losing their session variables while working in the system. It's an immediate click, not after timing out. I had one user do it while she was on the phone with me. Get the list of names, click on one, new window opens. All session variables gone.

The session variables are set when they log in, and the URL paths are the same because I use a variable to set them so anywhere that the full path is used it's identical across the entire site. Some places use relative paths, but this particular instance does not.

Comment: Dan - When the user returns to the original window the site continues to function correctly. It's only the new window that doesn't work. It is not consistent. I just got an email from one of the affected users 

"I also tried again in IE and first it worked, and then logged out and tried again and it didn’t work the next few times."

Browser settings are set by the University, and should be the same for all users. End users can't change them. Antivirus is also the same. 

I'm waiting on the ie version.

Comment: Adrian - I am not using jsessionID, so I'm assuming that I'm using CFID and CFTOKEN. I will admit I have never done anything with any of the three. 

The site is https if that matters. On the old server (we just set this one up a month ago) the site was http. Apparently this has been happening for months to some people, but they haven't TOLD me until now.

Comment: User that is currently helping me trouble shoot the problem (from a different building) is on the same OS and ie that I am on - Windows 10 and ie 11. Friday, it was happening inconsistently. It worked as expected once, and hasn't worked since then.

Comment: @michelleH it sounds like a cookie settings or other restriction is likely. You may want to check the browser settings and see if anything is different between your setup and the person helping you.

Comment: I suggest you go to Internet options->Privacy tab->Advanced and checked the 'Always allow session cookies' option. If the issue persists, try to reset the IE browser. Ref: https://imgur.com/a/FAWI3n1

Comment: From the user that has the issue, when I asked for them to check their settings - "It was not checked.  I checked it, and it worked for a little while but then reverted to the login prompt.  I had some success yesterday with IE too but then it went back…I have no idea of the rhyme or reason.  It’ll be working and then I’ll log out and back in to make sure it’s *really* working and it won’t be working anymore. "

Comment: Can you confirm the exact version of Coldfusion

Comment: ColdFusion 2018, with all current patches and updates.

Comment: I tried to search on Adobe Coldfusion forum and found this information on a similar kind of thread. It seems to be related to a session fixation hotfix applied to cf8, cf9 and the base install of cf10. This fix seems to create a situation where duplicate cookies can exist for a given token, causing Coldfusion to become confused and the user session to drop off. In all cases the crude solution to the problem is to manually delete the cookies from the clients browser. Ref: https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion/problem-with-session-variables-between-pages/td-p/4816984?page=1

Comment: Please post the exact version from the CF administrator. You may think it's up to date but it may not be.

Comment: Current version - 2018.0.07.316715

Comment: last installed patch - ColdFusion 2018 Update 7 - Thu, 12 Dec 2019 14:38:57 -0500

Comment: did you check the link I suggested to you? If the issue persists I suggest you to also consult the Coldfusion support. it can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: I'm going to try the manual replace. That seems so clunky though. This is something you'd think they would address!!

Comment: I tried adding in the code to force delete the cookies. Didn't work.

Comment: It looks you need suggestions from ColdFusion support team to narrow down the issue. If you did not contact them I suggest you do it may help to narrow down the issue.